# Is there a script to create Magento models?

Tags: database, scripting, magento, model

Can you provide a script to create Magento models, which also supports external database connections (which connect to something other than the primary Magento database)?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Go here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/intelligent_model_wizard

Dustin Oprea